# Polymer iron-scroll-threshold with iron-ajax

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

Is there an instruction/example on how do iron-scroll-threshold with iron-ajax.

Basically, I would like iron-scroll-threshold to load more content using iron-ajax overtime scrolling reaches threshold.

However, all examples I can find resort to using javascript to load more content via AJAX. If there is a way to do it all using just iron-ajax then I can keep the code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/turecox/edit?html,console,output) for a complete example.

In short, you need to handle the `iron-scroll-treshold`'s `on-lower-threshold` or `on-upper-threshold` event, where you call the `iron-ajax`'s `generateRequest()` method. Also you need to handle the new items in the `iron-ajax`'s `on-response` event.

Code:

```
<dom-module id="test-app">
  <template>

    <iron-ajax id="ajax" 
      url="https://randomuser.me/api/" 
      handle-as="json" 
      params='{"results": 20}'
      on-response="categoriesLoaded">
    </iron-ajax>

    <iron-scroll-threshold on-lower-threshold="loadMoreData" id="threshold">
        <iron-list id="list" items="[[categoriesJobs]]" as="person" scroll-target="threshold">
          <template>
            <!-- item template -->
          </template>
        </iron-list>
    </iron-scroll-threshold>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'test-app',

      attached: function() {
        this.categoriesJobs = [];
      },

      loadMoreData: function () {
        console.log('load more data');
        this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
      },

      categoriesLoaded: function (e) {
        var self = this;
        var people = e.detail.response.results;
        people.forEach(function(element) {
          self.push('categoriesJobs', element);
        });
        this.$.threshold.clearTriggers();
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**NOTE**

The example based on one of my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503451/iron-scroll-threshold-is-never-executed-after-first-list-scolling-is-end-in-poly/39525262#39525262) on a question related to `iron-list` and `iron-scroll-threshold`.

Comment: Is there a reason by the initial loadMoreData renders only 3 elements?

Subsequent loadMoreData renders many more elements.

Comment: There shouldn't be any but I guess there is a bug ... I am trying to fix it. I'll notify you when it is done.

Comment: @AtipAsvanund It is only a workaround, check out the JSBin again, I edited the `categoriesLoaded` function. When you load the first 20 item, call the `iron-list`'s `notifyResize()` function.